# R ggplot2 patchwork place legend on the top right hand corner

Tags: r, ggplot2

By default the legend is placed at the center of the white empty space towards the right.

Based on the data and code below, how can I place the legend on the upper right hand corner of the empty space?

Sample data and code:

```
library(patchwork)    
library(tidyverse)

gg1 = ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp, color = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

gg2 = ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

gg3 = ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')
     
gg1 + gg2 + gg3  + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably just to add a margin to the legend.

```r
gg1 + gg2 + gg3  + 
  plot_layout(guides = 'collect') & 
  theme(legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 200, 0))
```

[image]

Or change its vertical justification to 1 (which will keep the position stable as the device size is rescaled)

```r
gg1 + gg2 + gg3  + 
  plot_layout(guides = 'collect') & 
  theme(legend.justification = c(0.5, 1))
```

[image]